# Casting to :any breaks type check

Tags: typescript

In what scenario is it a good idea for the typescript compiler to accept the following:

```js
const foo: string = 7 as any;
```

I would expect some error message like `Type any is not assignable to type string`. I let a bug slip through to production because I missed an implicit cast to any on a computed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any` is assignable to anything, that's kind of it's whole point. To understand why it's there it's important to remember that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. A lot of JavaScript APIs returns arbitrary objects (such as `JSON.*`, `fetch`), and there's no way to write type declarations for them w/o `any`. Also `any` is useful for migration of existing code bases from JS to TS.

> I let a bug slip through to production because I missed an implicit cast to any on a computed property.

Set `strict` option in your `tsconfig.json` to `true`. That will forbid unknown types from being implicitly cast to any.

Comment: I always thought of `:any` as "_anything is assignable to any_". Rather than the other way around as you stated it. If a `const x:any`, then that const can be assigned a `:string` value. But if a `const x:string`, then it shouldn't be able to get a `:any` assigned.
Good tip with the `strict: true` though, just checked that it would have caught my bug...

Comment: "`any` anything is assignable to any" — that's correct, but the second "any" doesn't refer a type, it would mean any variable of any type ("any"s here also doesn't refer to the type `any` :)

Comment: Yes, so `const foo: string = 7 as any;` doesn't make sense to me. On the other hand `const foo: any = 7 as number;` does.

Comment: Whereas assigning `any` to a variable of `string` (or any type for that matter) is kind of analogous to casting to `void*` in C: powerful, but dangerous tool. I try to avoid using `any` in my projects.